# SVG Icon path doesn't show

Tags: html, svg

i have this svg-path as an header-icon. Now i want to add a letter to the path by using the gimp-method discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529470/is-there-a-tool-to-create-svg-paths-from-an-svg-file), but everytime i add the path for the "B" nothing is showing up. Any advice on what i am doing wrong? Here's the current (working) code and an image of what i'm trying to get.

Also, [here](https://wetransfer.com/downloads/092bee683d26298ce33f201c5ef3dbda20190430130638/f85140) is the .svg i'm using. Maybe there's something wrong with the svg itself and therefore i don't get the right paths in the text-file?

Hope someone is able to help me out with this issue.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 259 190"><title>Header Icon</title>
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grd" x2="100%" y2="100%" > 
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#000000"></stop>
        <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#bd2478"></stop>
        <stop offset="35%" stop-color="#54bdff"></stop>
        <stop offset="55%" stop-color="#96a318"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#000000"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
  <mask id="msk">
  <g fill="white">
 <path d="M82.908,66.963c0,13.656,0.293,27.323-0.197,40.963
  c-0.13,3.606-1.778,8.003-4.258,10.547c-18.482,18.958-37.344,37.546-56.108,56.229c-1.053,1.049-2.228,2.576-3.467,2.703
  c-2.113,0.216-5.052,0.212-6.277-1.038c-1.141-1.165-0.869-4.14-0.509-6.193c0.224-1.278,1.677-2.414,2.729-3.464
  c17.794-17.769,35.544-35.581,53.491-53.194c2.879-2.825,3.889-5.643,3.863-9.589c-0.162-25.312-0.095-50.628-0.062-75.942
  c0.003-2.149-0.281-4.591,0.615-6.368c0.949-1.882,2.993-4.146,4.841-4.433c3.271-0.508,5.05,2.112,5.257,5.317
  c0.193,2.985,0.079,5.992,0.081,8.989C82.911,43.314,82.908,55.139,82.908,66.963z"/>
 <path d="M134.135,67.524c0,13.986,0.044,27.973-0.051,41.959
  c-0.014,1.923-0.347,4.012-1.152,5.734c-8.87,18.968-17.852,37.883-26.844,56.793c-0.777,1.635-1.494,3.862-2.86,4.519
  c-1.983,0.951-4.805,1.446-6.739,0.722c-1.163-0.435-1.948-3.617-1.77-5.454c0.215-2.209,1.557-4.338,2.545-6.438
  c7.993-16.993,16.092-33.937,23.955-50.988c1.202-2.608,1.901-5.696,1.918-8.566c0.146-25.143,0.055-50.286,0.124-75.429
  c0.009-3.142,0.108-6.413,1.005-9.371c0.491-1.622,2.967-3.979,4.137-3.764c2.002,0.367,3.909,2.292,5.398,3.969
  c0.727,0.818,0.561,2.552,0.563,3.872c0.034,14.147,0.021,28.295,0.021,42.443C134.302,67.524,134.219,67.524,134.135,67.524z"/>
 <path d="M236.904,97.508c0,23.484,0.017,46.968-0.027,70.452
  c-0.004,2.139,0.213,4.638-0.778,6.317c-1.103,1.868-3.404,3.981-5.311,4.11c-1.435,0.097-3.737-2.516-4.446-4.382
  c-0.905-2.386-0.788-5.232-0.783-7.881c0.087-46.296,0.225-92.593,0.355-138.889c0.005-1.665-0.097-3.351,0.128-4.989
  c0.429-3.137,2.161-5.855,5.443-5.072c2.007,0.479,3.778,2.987,5.081,4.963c0.697,1.058,0.202,2.917,0.202,4.415
  c0.006,23.651,0.004,47.304,0.004,70.955C236.816,97.508,236.86,97.508,236.904,97.508z"/>
 <path d="M185.084,66.376c0,13.488,0.006,26.977-0.008,40.465
  c-0.002,1.495,0.436,3.379-0.289,4.401c-1.293,1.822-3.18,4.057-5.083,4.341c-1.436,0.214-3.658-2.087-4.823-3.761
  c-0.829-1.191-0.636-3.201-0.638-4.846c-0.032-26.477-0.044-52.954,0.017-79.431c0.005-2.303,0.055-4.841,1.004-6.83
  c0.76-1.593,3.046-3.624,4.425-3.466c1.825,0.209,3.826,2.09,4.988,3.777c0.804,1.168,0.393,3.225,0.396,4.884
  C185.094,39.399,185.084,52.888,185.084,66.376z"/>
</g> 
  </mask>
  </defs>
   <g style="mask: url(#msk)">
  <rect x="-2000" y="0" width="2259" height = "2000" fill='url(#grd)' >
     <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 2000,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0s"
        calcMode="linear" 
        dur="10s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

[image]

Comment: Your question is a little confusing. The SVG you included and the SVG you link to are different. It's not clear what you are trying to do because of that.

Comment: The SVG posted in your question won't work as a stand-alone SVG file (ie included via `<img>` etc). That's because it needs to have the correct `xmlns` attribute ( `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`).  Use the linked file for comparison.

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the path for the B outside the masked group like so:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 259 190"><title>Header Icon</title>
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grd"> 
       <stop offset="0" stop-color="black" />
        </linearGradient>
  <mask id="msk">
  <g fill="white">
 <path  d="M82.908,66.963c0,13.656,0.293,27.323-0.197,40.963
  c-0.13,3.606-1.778,8.003-4.258,10.547c-18.482,18.958-37.344,37.546-56.108,56.229c-1.053,1.049-2.228,2.576-3.467,2.703
  c-2.113,0.216-5.052,0.212-6.277-1.038c-1.141-1.165-0.869-4.14-0.509-6.193c0.224-1.278,1.677-2.414,2.729-3.464
  c17.794-17.769,35.544-35.581,53.491-53.194c2.879-2.825,3.889-5.643,3.863-9.589c-0.162-25.312-0.095-50.628-0.062-75.942
  c0.003-2.149-0.281-4.591,0.615-6.368c0.949-1.882,2.993-4.146,4.841-4.433c3.271-0.508,5.05,2.112,5.257,5.317
  c0.193,2.985,0.079,5.992,0.081,8.989C82.911,43.314,82.908,55.139,82.908,66.963z"/>
 <path d="M134.135,67.524c0,13.986,0.044,27.973-0.051,41.959
  c-0.014,1.923-0.347,4.012-1.152,5.734c-8.87,18.968-17.852,37.883-26.844,56.793c-0.777,1.635-1.494,3.862-2.86,4.519
  c-1.983,0.951-4.805,1.446-6.739,0.722c-1.163-0.435-1.948-3.617-1.77-5.454c0.215-2.209,1.557-4.338,2.545-6.438
  c7.993-16.993,16.092-33.937,23.955-50.988c1.202-2.608,1.901-5.696,1.918-8.566c0.146-25.143,0.055-50.286,0.124-75.429
  c0.009-3.142,0.108-6.413,1.005-9.371c0.491-1.622,2.967-3.979,4.137-3.764c2.002,0.367,3.909,2.292,5.398,3.969
  c0.727,0.818,0.561,2.552,0.563,3.872c0.034,14.147,0.021,28.295,0.021,42.443C134.302,67.524,134.219,67.524,134.135,67.524z"/>
 <path d="M236.904,97.508c0,23.484,0.017,46.968-0.027,70.452
  c-0.004,2.139,0.213,4.638-0.778,6.317c-1.103,1.868-3.404,3.981-5.311,4.11c-1.435,0.097-3.737-2.516-4.446-4.382
  c-0.905-2.386-0.788-5.232-0.783-7.881c0.087-46.296,0.225-92.593,0.355-138.889c0.005-1.665-0.097-3.351,0.128-4.989
  c0.429-3.137,2.161-5.855,5.443-5.072c2.007,0.479,3.778,2.987,5.081,4.963c0.697,1.058,0.202,2.917,0.202,4.415
  c0.006,23.651,0.004,47.304,0.004,70.955C236.816,97.508,236.86,97.508,236.904,97.508z"/>
 <path d="M185.084,66.376c0,13.488,0.006,26.977-0.008,40.465
  c-0.002,1.495,0.436,3.379-0.289,4.401c-1.293,1.822-3.18,4.057-5.083,4.341c-1.436,0.214-3.658-2.087-4.823-3.761
  c-0.829-1.191-0.636-3.201-0.638-4.846c-0.032-26.477-0.044-52.954,0.017-79.431c0.005-2.303,0.055-4.841,1.004-6.83
  c0.76-1.593,3.046-3.624,4.425-3.466c1.825,0.209,3.826,2.09,4.988,3.777c0.804,1.168,0.393,3.225,0.396,4.884
  C185.094,39.399,185.084,52.888,185.084,66.376z"/>
</g> 
  </mask>
  </defs>
   <g style="mask: url(#msk)">
  <rect x="-2000" y="0" width="2259" height = "2000" fill='url(#grd)' >
     <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 2000,0; 0,0" 
        begin="0s"
        calcMode="linear" 
        dur="10s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  </g>
  
 
 <path id="letterB" d="M141.864,42.852c2.736-0.576,7.057-1.008,11.449-1.008c6.264,0,10.297,1.08,13.32,3.528
  c2.521,1.872,4.033,4.752,4.033,8.568c0,4.681-3.097,8.785-8.209,10.657v0.144c4.608,1.152,10.009,4.968,10.009,12.169
  c0,4.176-1.656,7.345-4.104,9.721c-3.384,3.096-8.856,4.537-16.777,4.537c-4.32,0-7.633-0.288-9.721-0.576V42.852z M148.129,62.726
  h5.688c6.624,0,10.513-3.457,10.513-8.137c0-5.688-4.32-7.921-10.657-7.921c-2.88,0-4.536,0.216-5.544,0.432V62.726z
   M148.129,85.983c1.224,0.216,3.024,0.288,5.256,0.288c6.48,0,12.457-2.376,12.457-9.433c0-6.625-5.688-9.361-12.528-9.361h-5.185
  V85.983z"/>

</svg>
```

Comment: I'm not very sure I understand you. Try adding the path for the B to the `<g fill="white">` inside the mask.