# converting SVG HTML to SVG Paths issue

Tags: html, css, svg, gimp

I have a question mark svg that looks like this:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="29" height="29" viewBox="0 0 29 29">
  <g id="Groupe_114" data-name="Groupe 114" transform="translate(-1503 -141)">
    <g id="Ellipse_35" data-name="Ellipse 35" transform="translate(1503 141)" fill="none" stroke="#D8D8D8" stroke-width="1">
      <circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14.5" stroke="none"/>
      <circle cx="14.5" cy="14.5" r="14" fill="none"/>
    </g>
    <text id="_" data-name="?" transform="translate(1512 163)" fill="#D8D8D8" font-size="20" font-family="Montserrat-Regular, Montserrat"><tspan x="0" y="0">?</tspan></text>
  </g>
</svg>
```

It is effectively an `SVG` of an info question mark inside a circle. What I needed to do was to convert it to `SVG` paths inside so I could bundle it directly inside my code. I followed the instructions over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529470/is-there-a-tool-to-create-svg-paths-from-an-svg-file) using `GIMP`, but final path that I get is just of the outside circle, not of the inside question mark. This is what I get:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="0.322222in" height="0.322222in"
     viewBox="0 0 29 29">
  <path id="Imported Path"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 28.50,14.50
           C 28.50,22.23 22.23,28.50 14.50,28.50
             6.77,28.50 0.50,22.23 0.50,14.50
             0.50,6.77 6.77,0.50 14.50,0.50
             22.23,0.50 28.50,6.77 28.50,14.50 Z
           M 29.00,14.50
           C 29.00,22.51 22.51,29.00 14.50,29.00
             6.49,29.00 0.00,22.51 0.00,14.50
             0.00,6.49 6.49,0.00 14.50,0.00
             22.51,0.00 29.00,6.49 29.00,14.50 Z" />
</svg>
```

I have used GIMP before for converting another SVG symbol, and it worked okay with that, so I am not sure why is GIMP returning the path of just the outside circle. Could anyone let me know how to best convert to paths so that I can get the path of the outer circle as well as the question mark inside? Thank you!

Comment: Why would you need a path to bundle it with your code?

Comment: you need to change the viewBox. Try `viewBox="-1 -1 31 31"`

Comment: the code for the angular web-component I am working on needs to be compiled into a single bundle of javascript files, and it may not work if I add the svg as a file inside my assets folder, more neat to have a path embedding

Comment: @enxaneta its not working on my end!

Comment: It should. You may also try `svg{overflow:visible}` in css. And as an observation: Your path is drawing the circle twice with different radius. But this is not visible at stroke-width="1"

Comment: Its still not visible :( I think it may be because the text field in the original svg is not being converted to a path? oh yeah I noticed that too!! I deleted the first circle and retained the second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the SVG the question mark isn't a path, it is reference to the font so it could be in Gimp's blind spot.

This slightly more complex process seems to work:

1. Open the file in Inkscape
2. `Path > Object to path` (this converts the circles, and the questions mark)
3. Save as new SVG (at that point this SVG could be satisfactory otherwise:
4. Open SVG in Gimp as indicate in link, importing/merging the path
5. Export the path to SVG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN"
              "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     width="0.322222in" height="0.322222in"
     viewBox="0 0 29 29">
  <path id="Imported Path"
        fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="1"
        d="M 11.80,17.98
           C 11.80,17.98 11.80,17.44 11.80,17.44
             11.80,16.93 11.85,16.50 11.94,16.14
             12.05,15.77 12.22,15.41 12.46,15.08
             12.71,14.75 13.05,14.40 13.48,14.04
             14.00,13.60 14.40,13.23 14.68,12.94
             14.97,12.65 15.18,12.36 15.30,12.08
             15.42,11.80 15.48,11.46 15.48,11.06
             15.48,10.42 15.27,9.93 14.86,9.58
             14.45,9.23 13.85,9.06 13.06,9.06
             12.41,9.06 11.83,9.15 11.32,9.32
             10.81,9.48 10.33,9.67 9.86,9.90
             9.86,9.90 9.24,8.50 9.24,8.50
             9.77,8.22 10.36,7.99 11.00,7.80
             11.65,7.61 12.38,7.52 13.18,7.52
             14.45,7.52 15.43,7.83 16.12,8.46
             16.81,9.09 17.16,9.94 17.16,11.02
             17.16,11.62 17.06,12.13 16.86,12.56
             16.67,12.97 16.40,13.36 16.04,13.72
             15.69,14.07 15.28,14.44 14.80,14.84
             14.36,15.21 14.02,15.54 13.78,15.82
             13.55,16.10 13.40,16.38 13.32,16.66
             13.24,16.93 13.20,17.25 13.20,17.64
             13.20,17.64 13.20,17.98 13.20,17.98
             13.20,17.98 11.80,17.98 11.80,17.98 Z
           M 12.74,20.92
           C 12.74,20.43 12.85,20.08 13.08,19.88
             13.32,19.68 13.62,19.58 13.98,19.58
             14.31,19.58 14.60,19.68 14.84,19.88
             15.08,20.08 15.20,20.43 15.20,20.92
             15.20,21.40 15.08,21.75 14.84,21.96
             14.60,22.17 14.31,22.28 13.98,22.28
             13.62,22.28 13.32,22.17 13.08,21.96
             12.85,21.75 12.74,21.40 12.74,20.92
             12.74,20.92 12.74,20.92 12.74,20.92 Z
           M 28.50,14.50
           C 28.50,22.23 22.23,28.50 14.50,28.50
             6.77,28.50 0.50,22.23 0.50,14.50
             0.50,6.77 6.77,0.50 14.50,0.50
             22.23,0.50 28.50,6.77 28.50,14.50
             28.50,14.50 28.50,14.50 28.50,14.50 Z
           M 29.00,14.50
           C 29.00,22.51 22.51,29.00 14.50,29.00
             6.49,29.00 0.00,22.51 0.00,14.50
             0.00,6.49 6.49,0.00 14.50,0.00
             22.51,0.00 29.00,6.49 29.00,14.50
             29.00,14.50 29.00,14.50 29.00,14.50 Z" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this! This is absolutely the correct answer, and it should work but for some reason when I create separate paths for each of the M and C elements it doesn't work. Like I separate it into one path for the outer circle, and one path for the inner question mark. I'll accept this as an answer tho, because it works when I open the file separately.

Comment: Do you know if there is any way to figure out which of the paths represent the dot of the question mark, that is the part that is missing for me.

Comment: Look at the point coordinates. As far as I can tell, each line above is a [triplet](https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Paths-Basics) with the anchor in the middle. So you just search for the C with anchor coordinates close to (21,14). You can also count the anchors in a path editor and look for the C with an adequate count, but here the dot has two overlapping anchors(\*) so you could miss one. (\*) which could explain things.