# convert a svg to a "d=" </path

Tags: web, svg, vector-graphics

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Uploaded to: SVG Repo, www.svgrepo.com, Transformed by: SVG Repo Mixer Tools -->

<svg
   width="30.687769"
   height="14.306806"
   viewBox="0 0 30.687769 14.306806"
   fill="#none"
   stroke="#none"
   stroke-width="0.00048"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg86"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs
     id="defs90" />
  <g
     id="SVGRepo_tracerCarrier"
     stroke-linecap="round"
     stroke-linejoin="round"
     stroke="#cccccc"
     stroke-width="1.344"
     transform="matrix(0.76065258,0,0,0.70741729,-2.9117777,-9.8246121)">
    <defs
       id="defs66">
      <style
         id="style64">.a{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle
       class="a"
       cx="24"
       cy="24"
       r="9.4399996"
       id="circle68" />
    <circle
       class="a"
       cx="9.5299997"
       cy="24"
       r="5.0300002"
       id="circle70" />
    <circle
       class="a"
       cx="38.470001"
       cy="24"
       r="5.0300002"
       id="circle72" />
  </g>
  <g
     id="SVGRepo_iconCarrier"
     transform="matrix(1.1088044,0,0,0.99999865,-10.541819,-12.953461)">
    <defs
       id="defs77">
      <style
         id="style75">.a{fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;}</style>
    </defs>
    <circle
       class="a"
       cx="24"
       cy="24"
       r="9.4399996"
       id="circle79" />
    <circle
       class="a"
       cx="9.5299997"
       cy="24"
       r="5.0300002"
       id="circle81" />
    <circle
       class="a"
       cx="38.470001"
       cy="24"
       r="5.0300002"
       id="circle83" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

i have this vector graphic from the [Arcticons pack](https://github.com/Donnnno/Arcticons/blob/32535da16795f29bca75cac671285698e306041e/icons/black/nextcloud.svg?plain=1) but i need it as an

```
<path d="M22 12.018c-.008-1.65-1.328-2.985-2.96-2.993-1.18 0-2.192.723-2.667 1.74-.545-1.923-2.286-3.35-4.358-3.348-2.083 0-3.833 1.442-4.368 3.38C7.181 9.76 6.154 9.025 4.96 9.025c-1.632.008-2.953 1.343-2.96 2.99v.002c.007 1.648 1.328 2.983 2.96 2.991 1.193 0 2.22-.736 2.687-1.773.534 1.94 2.285 3.382 4.368 3.382 2.072 0 3.813-1.426 4.36-3.35.473 1.02 1.485 1.741 2.664 1.741 1.633-.006 2.954-1.342 2.961-2.99ZM4.96 13.252h-.013c-.668 0-1.21-.547-1.21-1.223v-.013c0-.694.537-1.236 1.223-1.236.685 0 1.223.542 1.223 1.236 0 .693-.537 1.235-1.223 1.236Zm7.055 1.608h-.013c-1.547 0-2.801-1.267-2.801-2.831v-.013c0-1.582 1.25-2.845 2.814-2.845 1.565 0 2.815 1.263 2.815 2.845 0 1.581-1.25 2.844-2.815 2.844Zm7.024-1.608h-.012c-.669 0-1.21-.547-1.21-1.223v-.013c0-.694.536-1.236 1.222-1.236.686 0 1.223.542 1.223 1.236 0 .693-.537 1.236-1.223 1.236Z"></path>
```

string and i don't know how to convert it, i have looked everywhere but cant find a solution, i tried to convert it with inkscape, gimp and krita, i found this [guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11529470/is-there-a-tool-to-create-svg-paths-from-an-svg-file) but it didn't work, maybe the ctrl + shift + c didnt work as expected?
i tried a lot of thing but it didnt work at all and im running out of ideas to type and describe stack Overflow.

Comment: I just passed it into this online converter: https://thednp.github.io/svg-path-commander/convert.html and it converts quite well

Comment: If you're using an older version of inkscape you might also need to convert styles to attributes e.g `stroke="#000"` `fill="none"`. Otherwise you might see only  filled circles. Besides the original svg is way cleaner  than your posted svg. So it might be easier to convert this version.